# bash updating variable with variable name with text

Tags: bash, variables, variable-assignment

Hello and thank you for your assistance in advance.
I am trying to update a variable that has a variable name within it.

I am trying to keep it simple as follow:

```
loc=abc 
value='Jul 02 2018 12:01' 
echo ${loc}datetime #results in abcdatetime 
eval ${loc}datetime="\"$value\"" 
echo $abcdatetime results in Jul 02 2018 12:01
```

is there a way to do something similar like 
    ${loc}datetime=$(value); 
    or 
    $(({loc}datetime=$value)) 
I want to get away from using "eval" and the "\$value\"" 
 Thank you again  SteveO.

Comment: For an extended discussion, see [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables).

Comment: ...that said, an associative array probably makes more sense for your use case. `declare -A datetime; datetime["abc"]='Jul 02 2018 12:01'`; no need for multiple variables at all, just make the one variable you have be a map from strings to strings.

Comment: Thank you however the time/date is not being generated it is part of a value being read in from a file and assigned to value.   Then I need to take that $value and assign it to another variable ${loc}xyz....

Comment: and yes the documentation shows the method I am currently useing eval "${ref}=\$value"

Comment: which is eval ${loc}abc="\"$value\""

Comment: What does the generated vs read-from-a-file distinction matter at all? Why do you think this means you can't use the answers from the preexisting question?

Comment: ...and if you read the FAQ entry more carefully, it shows plenty of non-`eval`-based approaches; indeed, [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) goes into detail on why `eval` shouldn't be used.

Comment: To clarify my suggestion about using associative arrays above -- a program that's designed well won't depend on variables named `${loc}xyz` at all, and should use `loc[$xyz]` instead. Even `xyz${loc}` is a better convention, because you can iterate over all variables whose names start with a prefix efficiently, but can't do the same with a suffix. So *if you can*, you should change the larger program to no longer ask you to set variables named with the form `${loc}xyz`. If you can't, though, the linked question and FAQ both go into details on how to do what you're asking for.

Comment: Take `printf -v "${loc}datetime" '%s' "$value"`, for example -- in no way does it care whether `loc` comes from a file.